# Doesn’t an adjective describe a meaning of the noun?

Tags: adjectives, modifiers

I don’t understand ‘once-young adult’ is a possible phrase. Adjectives should describe a meaning of a noun, but ‘once-young’ does not qualify the noun because ‘adult’ means an old person.

Comment: Try reading the answers and comments!

Comment: "adult" doesn't mean "old", it means "fully-grown". And [***young adult***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_adult) is an extremely common word-pair (so common it gets its own Wikipedia definition page! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An adjective does not 'describe the meaning' of a noun. An adjective is a word that tells us more about a noun. It "describes" or "modifies" a noun. For example, 'the big dog' tells us that the dog is big, which 'the dog' does not. A once-young adult is an adult who was once young. Of course, the phrase may be pointless, since all adults were once young, but that does not make it ungrammatical. If I had a red car, and I painted it blue, I could correctly talk about my 'once-red car'.

[What is an adjective?](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/adjective-what.htm#:%7E:text=An%20adjective%20is%20a%20word,a%20green%20car)

Comment: https://www.lexico.com/definition/adjective

Comment: but it says differently

Comment: @user132175 - 'A word naming an attribute of a noun', which is what I said.

Comment: How youth can be an attribute of ‘adult’?

Comment: @user132175 - 'once-young' is a [compound adjective](https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/adjectives_compound_adjectives.htm) containing [once](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/once), a hyphen, and [young](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/young). It means 'formerly, or at one time, young'. All older people are once-young people.

Answer (score 1):

The compound adjective 'once-young' modifies the noun 'adult', and it means 'an adult that at one time in the past was young'.

> once  (wŭns)
> adv.
>
> 1. One time only: once a day.
> 2. At one time in the past; formerly.

https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=once

Comment: it’s not a verb, it’s an adjective how adjectives function as a verb?

Comment: an adult is an old person how does ‘young’ modify ‘old person’

Comment: Correct. It is not a verb. It is an adjective. Adjectives modify nouns. Adult means someone of legal age, not necessarily 'old'. As for how it works, please read what I said.

Comment: @user132175 - do not ask fresh questions in comments.

Comment: @user132175 He's not being mean. People can't find answers if questions are in comments. Feel free to ask another question the way you asked the first one.